# InfoPath Date Picker Control is missing the calendar icon on published forms

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

This seems to be a new problem others are also recently experiencing and is probably caused by the latest Microsoft updates. As far as I can tell, it is happening with all versions of InfoPath. I posted a question to this forum about it: http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/31763.aspx

I am using Win 7, InfoPath 2007 filler forms, SharePoint 2007 with IE11 in compatibility mode.  Forms published (to SharePoint) that contain a date picker control are missing the colorful calendar icon and instead now show a square gray box with a black "x" in the middle of it.  When I bust open a form template in design mode, the date picker icon shows up correctly as a calendar image and in color.

Has anyone else experienced this change in behavior and have any suggestions on how to fix?  I've googled with no findings as I think this behavior just started this week.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. Somehow even on PC's which I would not expect to see updates on i.e. XP, not properly connected to internet. I wouldn't expect to get much of an answer at this point though.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the instructions below are the solution for the Date picker icon issue in InfoPath.  I use Win7 and IE 11.

"Go to Internet Option > Security > Trusted Site and Add "about:Internet". You may need to uncheck require server verification for https"

Answer (score 0):

It has been suggested by the InfoPathDev forum that the solution by Microsoft at link below will solve this problem.  I can not verify its validity myself as my company IE settings are controlled by group policy which I am unable to edit.
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/31763.aspx?PageIndex=2

The answer was posted by forum user styson0311:
*"Go to Internet Option > Security > Trusted Site and Add "about:Internet".  You may need to uncheck require server verification for https"*

The forum moderator tried it and verified it works for her environment.

Comment: As a follow-up I just noticed this week that all the calendar icons are back to normal now. I am not sure what effected the change and when, but likely a Microsoft update because I never did change anything. It resolved itself.